# Form of fbrequest

Tags: iphone

I'm using fbconnect in my app to connect to Facebook. Whenever i code a feature, I must google to find the form like below:

```
//////
NSString *event = @"{\"name\":\"A party\",\"start_time\":\"1215929160\",\"end_time\":\"1215929160\",\"location\":\"Somewhere\"}";
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:event forKey:@"event_info"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.events.create" params:params];
/////
```

I wonder how can I know the format of string "event", or key @"event_info", or @"facebook.events.create". I try to find document of fbconnect that talk about format above but ... Anybody can help me about this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's here:
[events.create](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.create)